spring + elastic search + window not work

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/XContentFactory
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.index.MappingBuilder.buildPropertyMapping(MappingBuilder.java:114) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.buildMapping(AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.java:253) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.createMapping(AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.java:230) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.createMapping(AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.java:225) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.createWithMapping(AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.java:110) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:94) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 68 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1

good install elastic search ver 7.12 on windows
enter image description here
enter image description here
everything is good!
But i met above error!
and that error(error because of ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch. common.xcontent.XContentFactory) is not on google
please help me! I dont know what i have to do.
i did

check java_home on windows

check intelliJ sdk

googling



Can you please check the elasticsearch dependencies in your build.gradle file if they are there. Other than that you can click on the refresh button of Gradle on the top right side of the Intellij (assuming you are using it) and please check if the included library in File->Project Structure-> Libraries
This class should normally be here: https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-x-content/7.6.0/index.html
